# Docker container failed to create tzdb.dat (No such file or directory)

Tags: docker

I am running my application with multiple services in docker.
all the services failed to create the containers from latest images complaining the same thing.

```
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [d] starting at position 16 in conversion pattern.
2023-08-04T04:31:26.727100375Z Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile
```

followed by,

```
Caused by: java.lang.Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.20.0.8-2.el8.x86_64/lib/tzdb.dat (No such file or directory)
```

Some answers are there to copy the file from JRE to JDK. But those are for you when you run the service in your PC.
Seems a file missing in the container OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using a RedHat Universal Base Image as a base container, and struck this issue when installing and using the `java-11-openjdk-headless` package, version `11.0.20.0.8-2.el8`. An earlier version I was using did not have this issue.

It seems that this package version has no dependency on the `tzdata-java` package, even though it has to use its files.

The file `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.20.0.8-2.el8.x86_64/lib/tzdb.dat` is a symlink to `/usr/share/javazi-1.8/tzdb.dat`, which is in the `tzdata-package`.

Installing the `tzdata-java` package dependency resolved the error. In my case this was done by adding `tzdata-java` to the package install line, such as:

```
microdnf update -y && microdnf install -y java-11-openjdk-headless tzdata-java && microdnf clean all
```

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/7025428 (OpenJDK 11.0.20 FileNotFoundException: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.20.0.8-2.el9.x86_64/lib/tzdb.dat) recommends exactly this workaround until the dependency bug is fixed.

Comment: i've an quarkus application with the the same problem, and this solved my case:
Usually, Quarkus applications have boylerplate Dockerfile.jvm, in some cases, like this:
as per the friend's solution above, i made the following adjustment:
...
RUN microdnf update -y \
    && microdnf install curl ca-certificates ${JAVA_PACKAGE} tzdata-java \
    && microdnf update \
    && microdnf clean all \
    && mkdir /deployments \
    && chown 1001 /deployments \
...